# Updating value in nested Dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I can't figure out how to update a value in a nested dictionary, the value keeps getting overwritten.

I have a list `date_list = ['2018AUG15', '2017APR22', '2017MAR05', '2016FEB10', '2016FEB09']`

I'm working on building a nested dict and so far I have

```
import collections

date_list = ['2018AUG15', '2017APR22', '2017MAR05', '2016FEB10', '2016FEB09']
month_ditc = collections.defaultdict(dict)

for x in date_list:

    year = x[:4]
    month = x[4:-2]
    day = x[7:]

    month_ditc[year][month]= day

print month_ditc
```

which yields

```
defaultdict(<type 'dict'>, {'2017': {'APR': '22', 'MAR': '05'}, '2016': {'FEB': '09'}, '2018': {'AUG': '15'}})
```

This is close to what I want. The year and month are updating as I loop through, **but the day is not**.

I have tried the following but still nothing -

```
 try:
     month_ditc[year][month] = day
 except KeyError:
     month_ditc[year] = {month:day}
```

I would like the result to be

```
defaultdict(<type 'dict'>, {'2017': {'APR': '22', 'MAR': '05'}, '2016': {'FEB': '09','10'}, '2018': {'AUG': '15'}})
```

Comment: Can you show what you expect?

Comment: What is `ordered_string_list` ?

Comment: @TrakJohnson sorry, should be date_list. I changed the body

Comment: @MosesKoledoye I updated the body.  If there are multiple days in the same month. I need that reflected in the dict.

Comment: Looks like you want to append the `days` to a list?

Comment: Dict keys need to be unique. You need to store multiple days against a single month as a `key: list` pair, and append days to the list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your expected output is not valid dictionary, I suppose you want a list, you can try to use `setdefault()` method to set default value if key is not already in dict.

[setdefault(key[, default])](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault)

> If key is in the dictionary, return its value. If not, insert key with
>   a value of default and return default. default defaults to None.

```
import collections

date_list = ['2018AUG15', '2017APR22', '2017MAR05', '2016FEB10', '2016FEB09']
month_ditc = collections.defaultdict(dict)

for x in date_list:

    year = x[:4]
    month = x[4:-2]
    day = x[7:]

    month_ditc[year].setdefault(month, []).append(day)
print dict(month_ditc)
```

Result:

```
{'2017': {'APR': ['22'], 'MAR': ['05']}, '2016': {'FEB': ['10', '09']}, '2018': {'AUG': ['15']}}
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thank you for the clear explanation.